# DOM: cropping an element and using parentNode

Tags: javascript, dom

Consider this simple page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var upper;
    var lower;

    function crop() {
      //upper = document.getElementById('upper');
      lower = document.getElementById('lower');
      document.body.innerHTML = '';  
      document.body.appendChild(lower.cloneNode(true));
    }

    function up() {
      document.body.innerHTML = '';  
      document.body.appendChild(lower.parentNode);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="upper">
      Upper Div
      <div id="lower">
        Lower Div
        <button onclick="crop()">Crop</button>
        <button onclick="up()">Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So `Crop` button clears the body, clones the lower div and appends it to the body. The purpose of the `Up` button is to make the parent of the lower div visible ( `upper` div ) . In my first attempt, i tried to use `lower.parentNode`, which doesn't work because it is `null`. I think that is because the variable `lower` is now pointing to a DOM element, which is not part of the body. (*Is my understanding correct?*) But now consider the commented line:

```
//upper = document.getElementById('upper');
```

which does nothing but get a reference to the upper div. When i uncomment this line, `up()` starts working. What is strange here is that i am not using this variable in any way. Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: Works for me without the line commented out: http://jsbin.com/ibapal/2/edit

Comment: yep.. works just fine i dont see the error u described http://jsfiddle.net/Xn3ge/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `document.body.innerHTML = '';`, you're removing all child nodes of `<body>` from the *DOM tree*, but not destroying the tree structure of those nodes itself. If there exist no references to these nodes, they are also destroyed and garbage collected.

You have set *(global)* `lower = document.getElementById('lower');`, so there exists a reference to `<div id="lower">`, this means that although it may be removed from the *DOM tree*, it doesn't get destroyed or garbage collected, as it is "kept alive" by this reference.

Now here comes the weird stuff, because you're mixing *String* methods (`.innerHTML`) with *DOM* methods (`getElementById`, `appendChild`), the browser isn't sure what to save from garbage collection. It ends up deciding that `childNodes` of referenced nodes can stay, but `parentNode`s aren't a strong enough bond, so get destroyed. This means you don't uniformly get `null`, you can also get

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

When you set *(global)* `upper`, this saves `<div id="upper">`, because you now have a reference keeping it alive. It also saves `<div id="lower">`, because of `upper`'s `childNode`s being protected from garbage collection, too. This preserves the *childNode* / `parentNode` link between them.

---

It's also worth noting that `cloneNode` may cause *id* attribute conflicts, as **an *id* must be unique**, but by definition, **a clone is not unique**.

Comment: [cloneNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4) does not remove any attributes.

Comment: @RobG you're right, I must have been experiencing [`The duplicate node returned by cloneNode() receives a new uniqueID when it is added to another node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) when I encountered it in the past.

Comment: Note that MDN is a community Wiki, it is not authoritative at all (e.g. I don't know if any Mozilla developers contribute). Anyhow, that statement is demonstrably false and will be removed shortly… :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is there a way to make sure that the elements temporarily removed from the `document.body` not be garbage collected? Ideally i want to be able to click `Up` continously until i reach the top. Holding a reference to every node in the hierarchy seems hard.

Comment: You only need to hold a reference to an ancestor node (parent, parent's parent, etc), not every node. Please note that `document.body` will stop being an ancestor node as soon as you set `document.body.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You create a global variable called *upper*. When you run *crop*, you assign a reference to the element with id *upper*, which is stored as a global and remains available as a global variable referencing that element regardless of what you do to the DOM.

#### Edit

Just to explain further, by preserving *upper*, you also preserve all its descendants and their relationships so *lower.parentNode* still exists after you clear the body. But if you don't keep a reference to *upper*, then clearing the body also deletes any parent or sibling of *lower*, but not the descendants of *lower*.

Comment: yeah but he is not using the variable upper anywhere

Comment: "He" is when the statement assigning to *upper* is uncommented and *crop* is called.